# Deezer api options streaming duration

Tags: deezer

I'm getting some data of my Deezer account. When I'm trying to fetch my streaming_duration, it returns 0.

Besides, Deezer documentation is not accurate. 
[image: doc]

Does someone know why is this returning 0 ? Is this seconds or minuts?

My code is the following one :

```
$.ajax({
             url: 'https://api.deezer.com/user/'+userid+'/options?access_token='+access_token,
             success: function(response) {  
                 console.log('Duration '+response.streaming_duration);
      }
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deezer devs answered me by e-mail

The option streaming_duration is deprecated.